# OpenCL: Invalid Value

Tags: c++, properties, opencl

I've a problem to fill the cl_context_propeties in windows:

here is my code:

```
cl_context_properties props[] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,
    (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext,
    CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,
    (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC,
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
    (cl_context_properties)platform,
};
*context = clCreateContextFromType(props, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &err);
```

after those lines is the errorcode -30 in my err (-30 in the errorcode for CL_INVALID_VALUE)

has anyone an idea to fix my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the functions and terminate with a zero. Try this:

```
cl_context_properties props[] = {
  CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentContext (),
  CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentDC (),
  CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) platform,
  0 
};
```